# Not able to view 'contentsOf' function of NSData in swift4 and xcode 9.2?

Tags: nsdata, swift4

I have been scratching my head for more than a couple of days now as to how to get 'contentsOf' `init` method from `NSData`.

Today I tried using the `init` methods with a (.)dot operator,

```
i.e Data.init(contentsOf: fileUrl! as URL)
```

and at last it worked.

However, I am not very sure about it. Can someone please guide me through what is happening. It might be something very trivial that I might be missing.

Comment: What kind of issue you facing with NSData ?

Comment: I am not getting Data(contentsOf: URL), function to work. I had to change it to Data.init(contentsOf:URL). 
What is the difference between the two?

Comment: Xcode Autocomplete leaves a lot to be desired. I had a similar problem in my project once, and solve it with this: https://medium.com/@_achou/one-weird-trick-to-fix-autocomplete-in-xcode-9f19dc856944 May or may not help with your case